# How to keep the text vertically aligned in any condition?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

For example in the below image I want keep the text always vertically aligned in all condition. even if text is in one, two or three lines.

means the text should be vertically centered always. I don't want to add extra `span`

[image]

```
<div>
<img src=abc.jpg"> Hello Stackoverflow. Thank you for help me
</div>
```

I want to achieve with this html.

**Edit**

**And I don't want to give fix width and height to any element**

Answer (score 5):

Chris Coyier wrote an excellent tutorial on just this: http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

I've used it myself, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try with

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="" height="155px" width="155px" style="float:left">
    <div class="imageText">Hiiii <br/> how r u? <br/> use multiple lines</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.imageText {  
    display: table-cell; // this says treat this element like a table cell
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    text-align:left;   
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/BZZ4r/1/)

Note: `width` and `height` matters

Comment: but i can't give fixed width and height

Answer (score 0):

I really like the method described @ http://reisio.com/examples/vertcenter/