# css : div question regarding positioning {vertical align and background}

Tags: css

Hi I have three questions regarding this code,

http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/125/

1) why the div with black background not covering the div with red background?[done]

2)why is the text going outside the div its contained in?[done]

3) how do I make the image and text in the third div center and vertically middle aligned[couldnt find an answer for vertical alignment]

4) how do I make the black background cover 100% width as well as height .... width: 100% works but height: 100% doesnt?

Comment: for #3 refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729593/how-to-keep-the-text-vertically-aligned-in-any-condition/5729761#5729761) or post that as a separate question. Compound questions don't tend to get good answers to all their compound parts.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/116/ sorry I forgot to save it i have updated the question

Comment: @faraz I think thats just for text I have img as well as text ... basically i want everything in that div to be middle aligned vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) why the div with black background
>   not covering the div with red
>   background?

Because you haven't cleared your floats. One way to clear your floats is to add `overflow: hidden` to `#black`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/108/ *(I made your text white for visibility)*

A good article to explain floats:  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

> 2)why is the text going outside the
>   div its contained in?

The `div` is not wide enough to contain the text (assuming that your window is reasonably narrow). You can force the text to wrap by adding `word-wrap: break-word` to `#fl_dv`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/109/

> 3) how do I make the image and text in
>   the third div center and vertically
>   middle aligned

As suggested by @faraz, see: http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/127/

> 4) how do I make the black background
>   cover 100% width as well as height
>   .... width: 100% works but height:
>   100% doesnt?

You need to set `height: 100%` on all parent elements of `#black` to make `height: 100%` work:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/128/

Comment: I did add the third div I forgot saving it in the first place sorry!

Answer (score 2):

@koool; for soltuion

1)
you have given `float` to the child element `#fl_dv` .So, first clear it with `overflow:hidden`

```
#black
{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

2) your text in one-word so; you have to use `word-wrap: break-word;` to break the word.

```
#fl_dv
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: red;
    color: #000;
    word-wrap: break-word
}
```

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJMva/112/)

Answer (score 0):

all the divs need to be float:left add float:left to #black

```
#black
{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float on the red container and your red container will be inside the black container.

Answer (score 0):

1,2) margin: 0 auto; - center div. float: left; float it left..... just decide what you need.

```
#fl_dv
{
    /*float: left;*/
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: red;
    color: #000;
}
```